# origin of "5 seconds flat"

Tags: etymology, idioms

Does anyone know the etymology of this expression?

> "He ran down the street in five seconds flat"

I found this explanation of meaning at [Wordreference](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1643242) but would like to know where the expression comes from:

> "In seconds flat" is an uncommon way of saying in no more than a few
>   seconds.

What kind of word is *flat* in this instance? Is this a UK expression or used worldwide?

Sorry, I know that's 3 questions, but they're all connected.

Comment: This might be racing terminology perhaps related to the stop-watch.

Comment: @coleopterist *flat* for *exactly* predates clocks with second hands, quite a bit.

Comment: *Flat* for *exactly* may predate clocks with second hands, but *seconds flat* doesn't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Flat* has been used as an adverb to mean ‘exactly’ since the sixteenth century. The OED records its use in the context of various kinds of measurement as being of US origin. The earliest citation in this sense is from ‘Webster’s New International Dictionary of the English Language’ in 1909.

Comment: Anything for the contraction to "in seconds flat". It's immediately understandable (as long as you know the first expression), but it has always struck me as strange in The Beatles' "A Day In The Life". I'd wondered before if it was a pre-existent idiom, or coined by Lennon & McCartney to suit their meter.

Comment: @Jon Hanna. 7 returns for _in seconds flat_ from the COCA, and 1 from the BNC. All probably postdate The Beatles, but that in itself isn’t conclusive. No citations for it in the OED.

Comment: So, not conclusive, but still **possibly** a Lennon & McCartney coinage. Interesting, thanks.

Comment: @Nick wrote that he "remember[s] that phraseology being used growing up in England before the Beatles came into existence," so it is quite unlikely that it was a Lennon & McCartney coinage.

Comment: For the record, "A Day in the Life" (which contains the phrase "Made the bus **in seconds flat**") was written in 1967 and appeared on _Sgt Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band_ (1967). "Motorpsycho Nightmare," which appeared on _Another Side of Bob Dylan_ (1964), contains this lyric: "Rita mumbled something/’Bout her mother on the hill/As his fist hit the icebox/He said he’s going to kill/Me If I don’t get out the door/ **In two seconds flat** /“You unpatriotic/Rotten doctor Commie rat.”

Answer (score 5):

It's originally from the US but is now used worldwide, and the earliest examples describe times in running, bicycle and horse races that are dead on to the whole second, rather than a number of seconds and fractions (typically fifths) of seconds.

This may because the second hand was exactly *flat against* the second mark on the watch dial, and not in between. For a modern analogy, you can compare it to an exact measure of, say, a litre of flour where the top is levelled off and there's no discrepancy.

The *OED*'s first citation is a 1909 dictionary, but I found a 26-year antedating.

The *[National Republican](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn86053573/1883-05-15/ed-1/seq-1/;words=seconds+flat?date1=1880&sort=date&sort=date&sort=date&sort=date&sort=date&date2=1890&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&proxdistance=5&state=&rows=20&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=seconds%20flat&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1&index=9)* (Washington City (D.C.), May 15, 1883) gives horse racing results:

> Joe Murray, who is looked upon as a very possible winner of the handicap, went a half mile in fifty seconds flat by three watches, but pulled up seemingly tired.

*[The San Francisco Call](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85066387/1898-05-01/ed-1/seq-10/;words=seconds+flat?date1=1836&sort=date&sort=date&sort=date&sort=date&sort=date&sort=date&date2=1899&searchType=advanced&language=&proxdistance=5&rows=20&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=Seconds+flat&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=63&page=63&page=63&page=62&page=60&index=0)* (May 01, 1898) gives some times with fractions of seconds, and one in seconds flat:

> He took the sticks beautifully and in the fast time of 15 4-5 seconds. ... Morgan ran the 220 hurdles in 26 seconds flat, equaling Torrey's record made on an Eastern track.

Comment: I don't believe measuring cups were used in cooking until after 1883.

Comment: Yes ... the web says Fannie Farmer in her 1896 cookbook switched from using weight measurements to volume measurements.  On the other hand, teaspoons and tablespoons were used for measuring small quantities of stuff back in the 18th century (presumably because the scales people had didn't work well for stuff that light), so your derivation could still be correct.

Comment: @PeterShor: Interesting, but that was a modern analogy rather than an etymological claim :) I've clarified the text. Thanks!